# Laravel 5 required_if validation for radio buttons

Tags: validation, laravel-5

The laravel required_if validation doesn't seem to work when you have radio buttons.

I have the following rules:

```
'method'  => 'required|in:Email,Url',
'email' => 'required_if:method,Email'|'email',
'url' => 'required_if:method,Url'|'url',
```

In my form I have the following:

```
{!! Form::radio('method', 'Email', true ) !!}
{!! Form::radio('method', 'Url', false ) !!}

{!! Form::text('email', null, ['maxlength' => '255', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::text('url', null, ['maxlength' => '1000', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

But the validation doesn't seem to fire?

Comment: Does laravel support the '|' you're using? Never seen that used before

Comment: Yes it does. You can use it to separate different validation rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake - added extra apostrophes to the following:

```
'email' => 'required_if:method,Email'|'email',
'url' => 'required_if:method,Url'|'url',
```

Should be:

```
'email' => 'required_if:method,Email|email',
'url' => 'required_if:method,Url|url',
```